# How to initialize a vector of shared_ptr for classes that take one parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11

The following is the expanded version, which works fine, only I'd like to use an initializer list

```
vector<shared_ptr<Foo>> inputs = {
    make_shared<Foo>("foo"),
    make_shared<Foo>("bar"),
    make_shared<Foo>("baz")
};
```

So I've tried something like

```
vector<shared_ptr<Foo>> inputs2 = {
    { "foo" },
    { "bar" },
    { "baz" }
};
```

as well as with two brackets, or none, ie `{{ "foo" }}` and just `"foo"`.

```
std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo = { "foo" };
```

doesn't compile either, so I think this isn't a matter of vectors at all, but initializing shared_ptrs with initializer lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only reasonable version is the first one you suggested.
If you look at the [std::shared_ptr documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr), you will see that there is no constructor that gets the managed - object constructor arguments as variadic template. Meaning you will not find something like:

```
template<class T,class... Arg>
std::shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr(Args&&... args)
```

so you can't really do something like

```
std::shared_ptr<std::string> p("hi there");
```

It will not work.
What you can do for `std::shared_ptr` is construct it with `T*`, so this should work:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::string> p(new std::string("hi"));
```

Now, you might be thinking, "Hey! I can use it inside an initializer-list!" but no, this:

```
std::initializer_list<std::shared_ptr<std::string>> il{
        new std::string("hi there"),
        new std::string("hi there")
};
```

will not work, because that specific constructor has the `explicit` keyword on it, so it must be declared explicitly!

So eventually, you *can* write something like

```
std::initializer_list<std::shared_ptr<std::string>> il{
     std::shared_ptr<std::string>(new std::string("hi there"))
};
```

but as you see yourself, your first attempt is far simpler and shorter.

Summary: Given the fact that there is no `shared_ptr` constructor that passes the arguments into the managed object constructor, you can't really use `{args...}` as a valid syntax. Given the fact that the `shared_ptr` which gets `T*` must be declared explicitly, you can't do something like `{new T(args..)}`, so the simplest way is to use `std::make_shared`.

P.S. In your first snippet, the thing that is used to initialize the vector *is* initializer list. Except that its type is `std::initializer_list<std::shared_ptr<Foo>>` and not `std::initializer_list<Foo>` like the second snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something silly like this:

```
template< typename Cont >
void consume_append_shared( Cont& c ) {} // terminator

template< typename Cont, typename T, typename... Args >
void consume_append_shared( Cont& c, T&& t, Args&& ...args )
{
    typedef typename Cont::value_type::element_type ElemType;
    c.push_back(
        std::make_shared<ElemType> ( std::forward<T>(t) )
    );
    consume_append_shared( c, std::forward<Args>(args)... );
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
std::vector< std::shared_ptr<T> > make_shared_vector( Args&& ...args )
{
    std::vector< std::shared_ptr<T> > vec;
    vec.reserve( sizeof...(Args) );
    consume_append_shared( vec, std::forward<Args>(args)... );
    return vec;
}
```

See it live [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/248ec76e28bb0054)

It only works if T's constructor expect one parameter.